# Is there a way to multiply a multidimensional array without dividing the array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have 2 multidimensional arrays

```
A = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6]
      [3,4,5,6,7,8]
      [5,6,7,8,9,0] ]

B = [ [a,b,c,d,e,f]
      [g,h,i,j,k,l] ]
```

So I want to multiply these two matrices by modeling like this.

```
Output = [ [1*g +2*h+3*i+4*j+5*k+6*l],
           [3*g +4*h+5*i+6*j+7*k+8*l],
           [5*g +6*h+7*i+8*j+9*k+0*l] ]
```

The thing I've been trying to do is to split array A into A1, A2, A3 and array B into B1 and B2

```
A1= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
A2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
A3 = [5,6,7,8,9,0]

B1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
B2 = [g,h,i,j,k,l]
```

Then program them one by one in the following way.

```
LenData = len[B1]
Sum = 0
For i in range (LenData)
Output = A1[i] *B1[i]
Sum+= Output

Sum2 = 0
For i in range (LenData)
Output2 = A2[i] *B1[i]
Sum2 += Output2

Sum3 = 0
For i in range (LenData)
Output3 = A3[i] *B1[i]
Sum3 += Output3
```

Is there any other way to do this without spitting out array?. This is difficult for me to do on an array that has a lot of data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers1 = [1, 2, 3]
numbers2 = [4, 5, 6]
  
result = map(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers1, numbers2)
arr = list(result)
#print(list(result))
print(sum(arr))
```

Try this approach:
i used map and lambda both to get the list of product of 2 another list. Then used sum to get the total values from that one list.

You can also create a generic fucntion that take 2 list as parameter and give the list of product for given 2 lists.

Plz ask if there is anything i missed and if there is any issue with code/approach.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is very useful for this type of operation. Here is a little code that can achieve what you want.

```
import numpy as np


A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],
      [3,4,5,6,7,8],
      [5,6,7,8,9,0]]

A = np.asarray(A)

B = np.random.randn(2, A.shape[-1])

results = np.sum(A * B[1], axis=1, keepdims=True)

print(f"{results.shape = }")
```

out:

```
results.shape = (3, 1)
```

Note that the arg `keepdims` is just to stay with the shape (3, 1). If you want to have a vector of shape (3, ) as the result, put `keepdims` to False.